# Can I extrud multiple faces according to weight of a vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups, extrude

Can I extrude multiple faces each one of them separated ,  according to weight  of a vertex group

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the displace modifier. First paint your weight, then add the displace modifier and set it up with you vertex group, then play around with midlevel or strength to get desired result.[image]

Comment: I mean like in edit mode extrude separate faces but each face take its extrude strength from vertex group weight, in displacement they will stay connected surface